# Spring data extracting rows with list of composite primary key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am trying to extract data using composite key of other table, but here problem is, I have list of composite key. Below are the table.

```java
@Embeddable
public class IdRangePk implements Serializable {
    @Column("START_RANGE")
    private String startRange;

    @Column("END_RANGE")
    private String endRange;

    // default constructor
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "ID_RANGE")
public class IdRange {
    @EmbeddedId
    private IdRangePk idRangePk;

    @Column(name = "PARTY_ID")
    private String partyId;

    @Column("STATUS")
    private String status;    // expired or active

    // constructors, other fields, getters and setters
}
```

Here, ID_RANGE have composite primary key (START_RANGE, END_RANGE). So same PARTY_ID can have multiple combination of start & end range.

STATUS can be either "EXPIRED" or "ACTIVE".

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "MESSAGE")
public class Message {
    @Id
    @Column("MESSAGE_Id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "PARTY_ID")
    private String partyId;

    @Column("START_RANGE")
    private String startRange;

    @Column("END_RANGE")
    private String endRange;

    // default constructor
    
    // constructors, other fields, getters and setters
}
```

Here, I need to extract the messages having active ranges for a given PARTY_ID. Also MESSAGE_ID is the primary key.

So I divided it into two steps

1. Extracting active ranges for given party id

```java
@Repository
public interface IdRangeRepo extends JpaRepository<IdRange, IdRangePk> {
       List<IdRange> findByPartyIdAndStatus(String partyId, String status);
}

List<IdRange> idRanges = findByPartyIdAndStatus("123", "ACTIVE");
```

2. Extracting message from list of active IdRange

```java
List<String> startRange = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> endRange = new ArrayList<>();
idRanges.stream().forEach(range -> {
   startRange.add(range.getStartRange());
   endRange.add(range.getEndRange())
});

List<Message> activeRangeMessage = findByPartyIdAndStartRangeInAndEndRangeIn("123", startRange, endRange);

@Repository
public interface MessageRepo extends JpaRepository<Message, String> {
       List<IdRange> findByPartyIdAndStartRangeInAndEndRangeIn(String partyId, List<String> startRange, List<String> endRange);
}
```

My second step query is not right, it is extracting more rows than the expected as query is counter by individually field instead of whole (for startRange & endRange which is a composite key). Can someone please help me correct my query or provide an easiest way to extract rows. I have used derived method but @Query will also do.